# Return Random JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have JSON on AWS server that I access Using JQuery and inside that json file are a few hundred objects that I wish to loop through and pick out one at random. Then get the attributes for that object.

This is the JSON:

```
 {  
   "1":{  
      "title":"Sailing for Kids",
      "ISBN":"1909911267"
 },
   "2":{  
      "title":"True Spirit: The Aussie girl who took on the world",
      "ISBN":"413513243"
 },
..........
```

And this is how I am trying to get the json objects.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
  crossOrigin: true,
  url : "https://link/to/file.json",
  type : "GET",
  success:function(data){
     var randomItem = data[Math.random() * data.length | 0];

      // take only the element with index 0
      alert(randomItem[0]);
  }
});
});
```

However, the alert is only displaying one character. like so:

[image]

How do I loop through all the returned JSON file the file, select one object and then get the attributes (title/ISBN) so that I can use them?

Comment: 1. That is an object you're receiving, not an array, so it won't have a `length` property. At least not by default. 2. `data.length | 0` - that's a bitwise OR there.

Comment: @vlaz - `| 0` makes sense - it makes the result an integer

Comment: The `$.ajax` call will return a string, not an object.  It could then be changed to an object with `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: `dataType:'json'` and/or fix the server to properly return a contentType for json.

Comment: @KevinB I have done that, can you help me select a random one?

Comment: why? you already have code that does that, if you had an array in your json rather than an object (objects don't have a sort order or a length)

Answer (score -2):

```
[
 {  
  "1":{  
  "title":"Sailing for Kids",
  "ISBN":"1909911267"}
 },
 {
 "2":{  
  "title":"True Spirit: The Aussie girl who took on the world",
  "ISBN":"413513243"}
 }
]
```

you may need to construct JSON as above

Answer (score -2):

First I'd do `console.log(data)` or even `console.log(data[1])` to see what I actually get. It could be, depending on headers, that result is sent as a text and not an object, in that case you need to do `data = JSON.parse(data)`

And then, to get the actual length of the object, like it was suggested, you need to use Object.keys(data), or you may arrange your data in an array.

And if `n` is the length than `Math.floor(Math.random() * n)` would a random in that range.

EDIT: 
Not being careful, Object.keys(data) is an array of keys. The length you need is thus Object.keys(data).length

EDIT 2:

```
var keys = Object.keys(data)
var n = keys.length;
var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
var randomKey = keys[randomNumber];
```

Comment: ok, so the data[1] returns the 1 result which is awesome. Object.keys(data) returns a list of all the keys. Now... they keys skip like 10,11,14,15,22 so it might be best if I add those keys return from Object.keys(data) to an array and then select one at random. agree? Also not sure how to do that